# NoMethodError for foo_url in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm having trouble understanding an error I'm getting from a view after doing some namespacing:

**Request:** http : // dev /data/state_categories.json [GET]

**Error**:

```
NoMethodError in Data::StateCategories#index
Showing (dev_root)/app/views/data/state_categories/index.json.jbuilder where line #3 raised:

undefined method `state_category_url'
```

**File in question:**  **app/views/data/state_categories/show.json.jbuilder**

```
 json.array!(@state_categories) do |state_category|
    json.extract! state_category, :name, :id
    json.url state_category_url(state_category, format: :json) #<-- this is the line that is erroring
  end
```

I had some scaffolding setup for a resource and then decided to namespace under "api". I made a new "data/" dir in controllers and in views, and moved the resource's controller and view into those dirs, which seemed to be necessary. Now there is a method in one of my views that isn't being found, not sure what I need to fix it. I never needed to define this method before I moved everything, it just worked. Where did I break the magic?

**config/app.routes.rb**

```
  namespace :data, defaults: {format: :json} do
      resources :state_categories
  end
```

**app/controllers/data/state_categories_controller.rb**

```
class Data::StateCategoriesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_state_category, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /state_categories
  # GET /state_categories.json
  def index
    @state_categories = StateCategory.all
    debugger
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_state_category
      @state_category = StateCategory.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def state_category_params
      params.require(:state_category).permit(:name, :description)
    end
end
```

**Output of rake routes**

```
 data_state_category GET    /data/state_categories/:id(.:format)      data/state_categories#show {:format=>:json}
                     PATCH  /data/state_categories/:id(.:format)      data/state_categories#update {:format=>:json}
                     PUT    /data/state_categories/:id(.:format)      data/state_categories#update {:format=>:json}
                     DELETE /data/state_categories/:id(.:format)      data/state_categories#destroy {:format=>:json}
```

Comment: I don't think `state_category_url` is right based on your routes.  What does `rake routes` return, specifically for the route `/data/state_categories`?

Comment: @CDub  added rails rake output at bottom of question

Comment: @CDub --ah. I see, it has to be data_state_category_url ... good eye thanks

Comment: Let me know if that doesn't work.

Comment: works great thanks. if you answer I'll accept, otherwise I'll answer or maybe close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your routes.  I think you'll want to use `data_state_category_url` in your jbuilder template